# How to show count value as 0 on rows removed with WHERE (microsoft access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I have two tables where one table represent the survey with the location and the other table the people interviewed (there are many people for each survey).  I'm trying to show the count of people over a certain age in each location, however some provinces don't have anyone over certain ages therefore don't show in the resulting table.  I would like the count to show zero if no one is over a certain age.
I have:

```
SELECT a.location, Count([b.age])
FROM Survey AS a LEFT JOIN person AS b ON a.surveyid = b.surveyid
Where b.age >= 85
GROUP BY a.location;
```

I realize that the WHERE clause is what is eliminating the zero count results but I can't figure out the subquery I would need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation instead.  That means moving the boolean condition to the argument of the aggregation function

```
SELECT s.location,
       SUM(IIF(p.age >= 85, 1, 0))
FROM Survey AS s LEFT JOIN
     person AS p
     ON s.surveyid = p.surveyid
GROUP BY s.location;
```

Noticed that I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations of the table names.  This makes the query easier to follow.